# Bulk insert documents to ElasticSearch without updating when document exists

Tags: nest, elasticsearch

Is it possible to **bulk insert** data to ES without updating document content if exists by Id. Only not existing documents should be inserted, without any updates.

Comment: In my case it was better (faster) to get which document ids are already in ES and use bulk index for not existing (not bulk create).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use bulk `create`:

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"foo":1,"bar":"y"}
{"create":{"_id":6}}
{"foo":1,"bar":"y"}
```

The above request is for doc 1, which exists already and doc 6 which doesn't exist. The output of that request is:

```
"items": [
      {
         "create": {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "1",
            "status": 409,
            "error": "DocumentAlreadyExistsException[[my_index][2] [my_type][1]: document already exists]"
         }
      },
      {
         "create": {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "6",
            "_version": 1,
            "status": 201
         }
      }
   ]
```

Comment: It works but I changed logic to get some state from ES (document ids which were inserted) and bulk.Index<Doc>(op => op.Document(myDoc)) to have lighter request and response without error message (409). Thanks for answer.

Comment: @marcinn are you able to share the logic how you did it? did you check the document if it exists in the index settings?

Comment: @BenChiciudean I have switched in my project to sql... I was not able to found old repo with elastic so I can't help you.